# Placeholder : field label or sample data?

Tags: forms, input-fields, placeholder

I am designing a generic form. Every input has a label positioned right above it.

My question is about using input fields placeholder :

Should they be a reminder of the label (Ex : Label : *Username* , Placeholder : *Type your username*) or display sample datas (Ex : Label : *Username* , Placeholder : *chuckNorris*) ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be a short hint (in you example "`Type your username`") rather than an example data (`ChuckNorris`).

The reason for this is that Placeholders have the potential to be mistaken for pre-completed fields, especially at a glance. If you have placeholders showing sample data then that increases the possibility of people thinking the field has already been filled in.

The current [W3 Site](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text) gives the following advice:

> **placeholder** = string
>   Represents a short hint (a word or short phrase) intended to aid the user with data entry.

Note: It does go on to say:

> A hint could be a sample value or a brief description of the expected format. For a longer hint or other advisory text, the title attribute is more appropriate.

However **this is incorrect** and is being updated in a [future version of the W3 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute), partly because the `<title>` attribute is no longer considered appropriate or useful for these situations. The updated advice is (from the current draft):

> The placeholder attribute should not be used as a replacement for a label. For a longer hint or other advisory text, place the text next to the control.
>   Use of the `placeholder` attribute as a replacement for a `label` can reduce the accessibility and usability of the control for a range of users including older users and users with cognitive, mobility, fine motor skill or vision impairments. While the hint given by the control's `label` is shown at all times, the short hint given in the `placeholder` attribute is only shown before the user enters a value. Furthermore, `placeholder` text may be mistaken for a pre-filled value, and as commonly implemented the default color of the placeholder text provides insufficient contrast and the lack of a separate visible label reduces the size of the hit region available for setting focus on the control.

So, if you're going to be using Placeholders (and I'd probably think carefully if you are going to) then make sure it's a hint and not an example. But make sure you surround the form with the correct markup too (correct label and descriptive text if necessary) and style the placeholder so that it is clearly a placeholder and not a piece of data (but still with enough contrast to be accessible - which overall is no mean feat!)

Comment: I know this is a really old question (10 years!), but W3 still recommends the `title` attribute for some cases, it seems the draft didn't pass