# Search input placeholder text

Tags: website-design, search, placeholder

The client is real estate agency which offers offices for companies. I have got search input on the homepage. What kind of text will you put as a placeholder? When you type the complete search answer, you can press Enter on the keyboard or click on the button with "Search offices".

**I am thinking about:**

"Search offices"

"Eg. Barcelona, 1st street"

What do you think?

Comment: Very related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49191/placeholder-field-label-or-sample-data

Comment: What would the field *label* be here? Is that visible too?

Answer (score 4):

I would use "[image: search symbol]Search offices..."

- The search icon([image: search symbol]) is fairly universal and gives a visual cue as to what the text area is without first having to scan to the end of the text area to see a button.
- The text content (Search offices) is a clear explanation of the action to be taken.
- The ellipsis (...) indicates that there is something more to do there which is another visual cue that it's meant to be interacted with.

Every input method that you could use would have the option of using `enter` to submit a query, and a button is no longer a necessity.  If something isn't adding value, then it's detracting from the elements that are adding value, and so should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 'Search offices' as the placeholder inside the input, and remove the text in the button and use a search icon instead. This way you would have just one hint, and it's a better recognised pattern.

Comment: But what would the field label say? You'll basically be duplicating label and placeholder here. Is that OK?

Comment: I would just not use any label on top, everyone recognises a search box since Google introduced it without any label.

Comment: People who browse with mouse and screen may recognize it, but what about screenreader users or users with other assistive technologies? Don't just assume that because you have perfect eyesight that this is the case for everyone else. And also, Google exists purely for searching, so that is not the case for OP situation where the search field is one of the secondary (or even tertiary) features.