# Can I put a placeholder with a description or example in text fields?

Tags: ux-writing

I am a beginner at UX writing so I can use the wrong terminology - sorry about that. I am currently working on admin panel and have a lot of text fields for data entry about banks, users and so on.[image]

I wanna find out what exactly kind of text should replace 'placeholder' text.

For banks, for example, can I invent a name and use it instead of 'placeholder' or should I just leave it empty? Or for users, can I invent a user (name, fake email and so on) and use it in text fields? For example:

[image]

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but this might answer your question https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49191/placeholder-field-label-or-sample-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input placeholder: suggestion or example?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/131587/input-placeholder-suggestion-or-example)

Answer (score 2):

#### Don't feel compelled to put placeholder text in every field. Use it as needed, and for complex or persistent instructions, use helper text. Clarity, not style is your first obligation to the user.

Placeholder text can be useful in some circumstances, such as examples of simple data examples (e.g. name@email.com).

The downside of placeholder is that the minute the user enters the field, it disappears, [forcing the user to rely on their working memory](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/) to remember what was just there:

[image]

From Neilsen Norman, **[arguing against most placeholders](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-placeholders/)**

> If the user forgets the hint, which people often do while filling out long forms, he has to delete what he wrote and, in some cases, click away from the field to reveal the placeholder text again. In an ideal world, users would be entirely focused when filling out a form. But in reality, users multitask. They have different tabs open, or they might be pulled away by an email or phone call. For complex tasks, they might have to stop and go retrieve a document or order number. From our research on mobile usability, we know that mobile users are also frequently distracted and interrupted while using their devices. So, it’s important to help users pick up where they left off.

In this case, helper text is better: It's persistent, and can be larger than the input field. It also has more contrast than a placeholder (where too much contrast looks like it already holds a value), making it more accessible.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the disappearing placeholder problem mentioned above, I just used a system that used the 'example data' placeholder approach, and it was more work for me to realise "John Smith" wasn't me than "First name Last name", or that "jsmith@yourmail.com" wasn't real compared to "Email address". I half wondered for a second if it had somehow prefilled the fields for me.

Basically, the more realistic you make the placeholder examples, the harder it is to tell it isn't my real data I've already entered

Answer (score 0):

some of this might be just a matter of opinion. I like to use examples of inputs in the placeholder to avoid user errors.

Ex.:

- Name -> The user writes his/her entire name.
- Surname -> The user realizes there is a specific field for this and goes back to the name field to delete the surname there.

I use it as a way of avoiding error, but there are other ways of achieving that.

I've seen many sites that use the placeholder to indicate the correct format of the content. This could be very interesting for dates, phone number, IBAN...

Here you don't have to use fake data, just indicate the format, how to write it:

- Date: DD/MM/YYYY
- IBAN: NL_ _ - _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _ - _ _ _ _

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a very important question to be asked here, or you should be asking is - would that placeholder copy bring any value to the user? It will really help the person filling the form? Otherwise you could as well label the field "Full name" or "Name and surname"

When you focus on the field it will disappear and if you're counting on the user's memory to remember what was there you might be disappointed.

It might add too much clutter for a whole form to "feel" pre-filled anyway.
Sure, it could help on fields like phone number, but even then, instead of placeholder text, we can have explanations or auto-format the field content to the desired format (ex: most credit card processors' card number field or IBAN for banking apps).

If that placeholder text should act like instruction to the user then maybe it should be a helper text somewhere around the field, depending on how you handle field validations and error signaling as well.

I hope you do find the explanation helpful.
Keep up the good work!